# Drag and scroll - got horizontal but can't get vertical working

Tags: javascript, html

I got the horizontal grab and scroll working but stuggling to get the vertical working - what am I missing?

Working X horizontal but not Y vertical:

```js
const slider = document.querySelector('.genealogy-body');
let mouseDown = false;
let startX, scrollLeft;
let startY, scrollTop;

let startDragging = function (e) {
  mouseDown = true;
  startX = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
  scrollLeft = slider.scrollLeft;
  startY = e.pageY - slider.offsetTop;
  scrollTop = slider.scrollTop;
};

let stopDragging = function (event) {
  mouseDown = false;
};

slider.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if(!mouseDown) { return; }
    // move horizontally
    const x = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
    const scrollX = x - startX;
    slider.scrollLeft = scrollLeft - scrollX;
    // move vertically
    const y = e.pageY - slider.offsetTop;
    const scrollY = y - startY;
    slider.scrollTop = scrollTop - scrollY;
});

// event listeners
slider.addEventListener('mousedown', startDragging, false);
slider.addEventListener('mouseup', stopDragging, false);
slider.addEventListener('mouseleave', stopDragging, false);
```

Comment: It works fine. If you've set the `overflow-y` to hidden then remove it.

Comment: Thanks but not working for me. I'm using this code on codepen and if you paste in the above js then only horizontal scroll works.https://codepen.io/piyushpd139/pen/JjPpjZj

Comment: I checked your code. It's because the height of the child element doesn't overlap the parent elements element. for e.g. the height of the parent is 500px and the child elements are 400px in total. This won't cause a vertical scroll so the drag and drop vertically are useless. Vertical drag and drop would only work if the child elements height exceeds the height of parent element/

Comment: By parent, do you mean the .genealogy-body and the 'min-height: 500px' setting is causing the problem, since even if I change it to 10px it doesn't make a difference? If I minimise the browser window to a size so that the vertical scroll bar appears, there's no vertical drag and scroll, only scroll using the scroll bar.

Comment: Change the max-height to 200px and you'll see it's working